# Passing a template's template member type as a template template argument

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

A class `WithTTMember` has a template member type named `TT`.

```
struct WithTTMember {
    template<typename> using TT = void;
};
```

Another class `ExpectTT` takes a template template parameter:

```
template< template<typename> typename TT >
struct ExpectTT {};
```

`ExpectTT<WithTTMember::TT>` can be successfully instantiated.

A third class `ExpectTWithTT` expects a template parameter with a template member type named `TT`, and instantiates `ExpectTT` using it:

```
template<typename T>
struct ExpectTWithTT {
    using X = ExpectTT<typename T::TT>;  // this doesn't compile
};
```

I expect `ExpectTWithTT<WithTTMember>::X` to be the same type as `ExpectTT<WithTTMember::TT>`. However the code above is fails to compile.

I tried injecting the faulty line with a combination of `template` and `typename` keywords following compiler messages and my instinct, but I couldn't get it to work.

How can I express what I want?

Any C++ version is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`template`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/template) keyword to tell that `T::TT` is a template.

```
template<typename T>
struct ExpectTWithTT {
    using X = ExpectTT<T::template TT>;
    //                    ^^^^^^^^
};
```

Comment: Oh man, that was easy!

I started with `T::TT` and the compiler was telling me to add `typename`, which apparently is never good. Thanks!

Comment: @Helloer Yes, I agree usage of these keywords is confusing. :)

Comment: @Helloer You'll find this question especially helpful for reference: [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)